# code blocks osx allegro

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks, allegro

I am new to C++ and due to uni requirements we are all using Code Blocks. I use it on 10.10.5 OS X. Now I have to do a project that uses allegro5 library, but I can not install it! I have spent so much time trying to follow different tutorials like http://partitionseven.blogspot.com/2011/01/compiling-allegro-5-with-mac-os-x-snow.html with no success at all.
Is there any way to get it working?

edit

I first encouter a problem when specifing clang tool- there is no such a directory on my mac /Developer/usr/bin/clang. I could only find usr/bin/clang directly in finder, but the folder usr is grayed out- does it mean anything? 
I was able to find this path /Developer/usr/bin/clang only when I click on Xcode->show contents. So thats the first thing that is not going exactly as in the tutorial. Still I am able to run CMAKE but I get a log like this:

```
The C compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053
The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Check if the system is big endian
Searching 16 bit integer
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of unsigned short
Check size of unsigned short - done
Using unsigned short
Check if the system is big endian - little endian
Looking for include file dirent.h
Looking for include file dirent.h - found
Looking for include file inttypes.h
Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
Looking for include files sys/types.h, linux/joystick.h
Looking for include files sys/types.h, linux/joystick.h - not found
Looking for include file stdbool.h
Looking for include file stdbool.h - found
Looking for include file stdint.h
Looking for include file stdint.h - found
Looking for include file sys/io.h
Looking for include file sys/io.h - not found
Looking for include file sys/stat.h
Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
Looking for include file sys/time.h
Looking for include file sys/time.h - found
Looking for include file time.h
Looking for include file time.h - found
Looking for include file sys/utsname.h
Looking for include file sys/utsname.h - found
Looking for include file sys/types.h
Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
Looking for include file soundcard.h
Looking for include file soundcard.h - not found
Looking for include file sys/soundcard.h
Looking for include file sys/soundcard.h - not found
Looking for include file machine/soundcard.h
Looking for include file machine/soundcard.h - not found
Looking for include file linux/soundcard.h
Looking for include file linux/soundcard.h - not found
Looking for include file libkern/OSAtomic.h
Looking for include file libkern/OSAtomic.h - found
Looking for include file sys/inotify.h
Looking for include file sys/inotify.h - not found
Looking for include file sys/timerfd.h
Looking for include file sys/timerfd.h - not found
Looking for getexecname
Looking for getexecname - not found
Looking for mkstemp
Looking for mkstemp - found
Looking for mmap
Looking for mmap - found
Looking for mprotect
Looking for mprotect - found
Looking for sched_yield
Looking for sched_yield - found
Looking for sysconf
Looking for sysconf - found
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - found
Looking for ftello
Looking for ftello - found
Check size of _Bool
Check size of _Bool - done
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_PROCFS_ARGCV
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_PROCFS_ARGCV - Failed
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_SV_PROCFS_H
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_SV_PROCFS_H - Failed
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_VA_COPY
Performing Test ALLEGRO_HAVE_VA_COPY - Success
Check if constructors are supported - yes
Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create
Looking for pthread_create - found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Found OpenAL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework  
Found FLAC: /usr/local/include  
Performing Test FLAC_COMPILES
Performing Test FLAC_COMPILES - Success
Could NOT find DUMB (missing:  DUMB_INCLUDE_DIR DUMB_LIBRARY) 
WARNING: libdumb not found, disabling support. <http://dumb.sourceforge.net/>
Found VORBIS: /usr/local/include  
Performing Test VORBIS_COMPILES
Performing Test VORBIS_COMPILES - Success
Found Freetype: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib (found version "2.6.3") 
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.8") 
Found PhysFS: /usr/local/lib/libphysfs.dylib  
Found PHYSFS: /usr/local/lib/libphysfs.dylib  
Performing Test PHYSFS_IMPLICIT_ZLIB
Performing Test PHYSFS_IMPLICIT_ZLIB - Success
Could NOT find LATEX (missing:  LATEX_COMPILER) 
Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   allegro
   allegro_acodec
   allegro_audio
   allegro_color
   allegro_dialog
   allegro_font
   allegro_image
   allegro_main
   allegro_memfile
   allegro_physfs
   allegro_primitives
   allegro_ttf

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Generating done
```

The files that are generated by CMAke are

```
MacBook-Air-ukasz:build lukasz$ ls
CMakeCache.txt      cmake_install.cmake include
CMakeFiles      demos           lib
Makefile        docs            tests
addons          examples
```

Thank you @MikeKinghan, it seems like I am one step further- I don't get the error. But I've open the code blocks, pasted the example code(the one from tutorial), and I get an error while copiling

```
g++   -c /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.cpp -o /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.o
g++  -o /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_al_clear_to_color", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_create_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_destroy_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_flip_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_install_system", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_map_rgb", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_rest", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

edit

when I run the test application from Terminal with

```
gcc alleg5test.c -o alleg5test -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro -lallegro_main
./alleg5test
```

it worked- i got a black screen. So probably I have to "join the library with code blocks. any ideas- I have found only a tutorial for windows.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to share the steps you have taken and the concrete evidence of failure to reveal what you are doing wrong. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That looks OK, apart from Latex missing. Install Latex, fix the
policy warning as advised (see [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31561309/1362568)), run CMake again and then carry on
per the tutorial.

Comment: It's one question at a time on SO. You've solved the problem you posted
and that has enabled you to progess to a new problem (about which
I know nothing). Do your very best to solve the new problem
by your own efforts - including [learning how to use Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/User_documentation)
- and if you can't, post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reply due to SO restrictions but here is a possibility: Your Allegro libraries are built for i386 and don't include the x86_64 architecture. You can check libraries on the command line but it won't always tell you what you have unless you have both i386 and x86_64. You do so like this:

`file liballegro.a` or `file liballegro.dylib`

If it says anything about x86_64 then I am wrong. If it doesn't that might be the problem. Then you have two options: either build Allegro as x86_64 or build your program as i386. To build Allegro as x86_64 and i386, add the following to your CMake command like this:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64;i386" ...`

Or just specify that variable in cmake-gui. You can leave out one or the other by removing it and the semicolon.

Now to build your program with a specific architecture, if you're using gcc from the command line like that tutorial you linked, use the `-m` switch. To build for i386, use `-m32` and to build for x86_64 use `-m64` (or you can use `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` for both I believe (not sure and not at a Mac right now.) So your command would be:

`gcc -m64 ...` where ... is the same as before.