# Guard code depending on CMake version

Tags: cmake, versioning

Our project has a `CMakeList.txt`, but its not our primary build system. On Mac OS X, using [Cmake generates a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31561309) (nothing new here):

```
MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets...
```

The cited question/answer states to use either `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)` or `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)`. Our problem is, [the feature is too new](http://blog.kitware.com/upcoming-in-cmake-2-8-12-osx-rpath-support/) and it breaks existing Cmake installations, like those found on Ubuntu LTS's or CentOS. We need to guard its use for Cmake >= 2.8.12, but the [blog post](http://blog.kitware.com/upcoming-in-cmake-2-8-12-osx-rpath-support/) does not discuss how to do it.

Searching is not producing useful results: [how to guard cmake directive](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+guard+cmake+directive). My inability to find relevant results is probably due to my inexperience with Cmake (others were supposed to maintain it).

How do we guard `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)` or `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)`?

---

Please note, I'm *not* looking for `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5 FATAL_ERROR)`. The best I can tell it does not do a damn thing. From testing we know it does not reject `target_include_directories` even though `target_include_directories` does not meet minimum requirements and causes failures in down level clients like Ubuntu LTS's.

I think what I'm looking for is closer to a C preprocessor macro:

```
#define 2_8_12 ...
#if CMAKE_VERSION >= 2_8_12
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
  message("Not setting RPATH")
else()
  set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
endif()
```

Docs for 2.8.10 here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_VERSION

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Let me test it and get back to accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you just want to overcome the warning, you may check whether policy, generating this warning, *exists*:

```
if(POLICY CMP0042)
    set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
endif()
```

This "if" form is decribed in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html).

Comment: I might be wrong, but for older versions that do know CMP0042, CMake emits a warning or even an error.

Comment: Do you mean "for older versions that **don't know** CMP0042 ..."? Otherwise I don't see a problem with my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I believe that policies describe **every incompatibility** with older CMake versions. So if project has been successfully built on pre 2.8.12, and warning/error is generated for it on new version of CMake, than this warning/error can be disabled using policy mechanism.

Comment: Sure. My point is, if the CMake version is older then CMP0042, it will fail. Checking for the version might be the better option, depending on other version constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to handle it properly for CMake? There is a wiki page called [CMake RPATH handling](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling). According to that you can add something like this:

```
string (TOLOWER ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} TARGET_OS)

if (TARGET_OS STREQUAL darwin)
    set (CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH TRUE)
    set (CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

    # Fix runtime paths on OS X 10.5 and less
    if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION VERSION_LESS "10.0.0")
        set (CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
    else()
        set (CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
    endif()

    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

    list (FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" isSystemDir)

    if ("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
        set (CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
    endif ("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
endif()
```

This snippet should fix CMP0042 with any 2.8.x version.

Comment: `RPATH` can cause a security audit failure. it will always generate a finding. On OS X,we want to see `install_names`. On Linux, we don't want to see an RPATH.

Comment: @jww CMake CMP0042 is only applicable to OS X builds, that's why I'm suggesting you to fix RPATH only for OS X builds. The above snippet woldn't touch anything on Linux.

Comment: `RPATH` will still generate a finding. Don't use rpath's. The questions asks in the context of both `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)` and `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)`. But our choice was already made - `set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)`. We did not mention it to avoid the protracted debates.

Comment: @jww Have you tried to set `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` variable to completely disable `RPATH` management by CMake?